# On the exceptional divisor of the resolution of indeterminacy locus of rational map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, blow-ups

Let $f:X \dashrightarrow Y$ be a rational map between smooth, projective varieties over $\mathbb{C}$. We know that there is a resolution of the indeterminacy locus using which we obtain a smooth, projective variety $W$ along with a proper, birational morphism $g:W \to X$ which is an isomorphism over the locus where $f$ is defined. The composition $f \circ g$ gives a regular morphism from $W$ to $Y$. I do not quite understand the construction, namely where the exceptional divisor of the blow-up morphism $g$ maps to in $X$ or $Y$. In particular, can I say that the exceptional divisor maps to a *proper*, closed subvariety of $X$ and $Y$ (under the morphisms $g$ and $f \circ g$, respectively)? If this is false, is it possible for the exceptional divisor to map surjectively to $Y$?

Comment: Consider the projection $\mathbb{P}^n --> \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ from a point $p\in\mathbb{P}^n$. To resolve the indeterminacy, you just blow up $p$. The exceptional divisor is the projective space $\mathbb{P}(T_p(\mathbb{P}^n))$, it maps bijectively to $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$.

Comment: I am a beginner at this, but I look at it this way: let G be the graph of f in XxY, and let V be the closure of G.  V is essentially your W.  Then V projects birationally to X, essentially by your g, with some positive diml fibers, and also projects to Y, regularly, essentially your map fog.  The exceptional set is the closed locus in V of points lying on positive diml fibers of g.  To get your W, you resolve singularities of V by blowing up this locus.  You can see the except'l loci in V and W map to proper subloci in X, not nec in Y, as in abx's example.

Comment: @roysmith and abx: Thanks for the answers